# Batch input using Apache Cayenne

Tags: commit

I tried to process any pack o data, by inputing this into the Oracle database under Cayenne environment. The tests based on thousands rows inserted in one loop.

Each row has its unique ID and in this case used Oracle Sequence to generate the ID.

I noticed, examined Cayenne log, framework used the sequnece correct, but in stage of commit an exception thrown in case of unique ID unconsistency.

When I trurned off PK constraint on this table, the commit phase was done without any exceptions, but after that in the table I could find some duplicated ID even the obtaing it from the sequence was fine.

Has anybody any idea?

Thanks in advance
Chris.